# Неупорядоченный список SQLite (Python)

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite

Работаю с БД в `SQLite`, некоторые функции получают данные из таблиц базы данных. Пример:

```
def db_upgrades_load_names():

    _names = cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM names").fetchall()
    ...
```

Метод `fetchall()` возвращает упорядоченный список записей. Мне же нужно, чтобы записи выводились в порядке их расположения в таблице БД. Например:

Данные в таблице идут в произвольном порядке.

Методы `fetchall()`, `fetchmany()` и `fetchone()` возвращают отсортированный по алфавиту список.

Каким образом я могу возвращать значения без сортировки по алфавиту, т.е. в том же порядке, в котором они изначально стоят?

Comment: В sql в целом (и в sqlite в частности) нет никакого гарантированного порядка записей (а сортировка по алфавиту это скорее всего случайность). Если вам нужен какой-то определённый порядок — добавляйте числовой столбец, который будет обозначать этот самый порядок, и делайте ORDER BY по этому столбцу

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

У вас скорее всего есть поле ID или что-то подобное. Или если нет, создайте его сделайте на нём Primary Key и Auto Increment. Сами INSERTы менять не придётся из-за этих двух настроек.

Потом в SELECT используйте ORDER BY id. И вы получите все строки в бд отсортированные по id.